# javascript filter multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I am not familiar with javascript but I need to use it for a callback with Bokeh. I created a multidimensional array with the following content (pseduo code)

```
items =[
 ["id", Array(2898)],
 ["NAME", Array(2898)],
 ["ADDRESS", Array(2898)],
 ["PHONE", Array(2898)],
];
```

I would like to create a new array containing a subset filtered by an array of "ids"

I tried using filter and some but can't seem to get it work. here is what I got so far

```
let items = Object.keys(items_obj).map((key) => [key, items_obj[key]]); 
let filter_items = items.filter(function(item){
return item.some(e => e['id'] === ids[0]);
```

Is there a simplye whay to do this? In python, I would simply filter df[df['ids'].isin([3, 6])]

Many thanks

Comment: SHow the input and expected output

Comment: Looks like `items` should be an array of objects instead: `items = [ {id: ..., NAME: ... ADDRESS: ..., PHONE: ... }, { id: ..., NAME: ..., ADDRESS: ..., PHONE: ... }, ... ]`

Comment: Agree with above. If you're creating this, would be better to be an array of objects from the start. Is there a reason you can't do that? More detail would help

Comment: Many thanks,  in fact yes items_obj is an array of objects like this [ {id: [id1, id2,...]}, {NAME: [Name1, Name2,...]}, ...] and then I get the error Filter is not a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to extract a "column" of data from a matrix, you can find the column index by find the value index within the corresponding key array.

```js
const data = [
  ["id", [1, 2, 3]],
  ["NAME", ['Bob', 'Joe', 'Nancy']],
  ["ADDRESS", [1, 2, 3]],
  ["PHONE", [1, 2, 3]]
];

const
  itemsObj = Object.fromEntries(data), // Matrix to Object
  itemsArr = Object.entries(itemsObj); // Object to Matrix

const getFrame = (dataFrames, key, value) => {
  const [ , keyValues ] = dataFrames.find(([key]) => key === key);
  const index = keyValues.indexOf(value);
  return dataFrames.map(([k, v]) => [ k, v.find((w, i) => i === index) ]);
};

const
  frame = getFrame(data, 'id', 2),
  frameObj = Object.fromEntries(frame);
  
console.log(frameObj);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

If you want to select a range of "frames", you can modify the program as seen below:

```js
const data = [
  ["id", [1, 2, 3]],
  ["NAME", ['Bob', 'Joe', 'Nancy']],
  ["ADDRESS", [1, 2, 3]],
  ["PHONE", [1, 2, 3]]
];

const getFrames = (dataFrames, key, values) => {
  const [ , keyValues ] = dataFrames.find(([key]) => key === key);
  const indicies = values.map(val => keyValues.indexOf(val)).filter(i => i > -1);
  return indicies.map(index =>
    dataFrames.map(([k, v]) =>
      [k, v.find((x, i) => i === index)]));
};

const
  frames = getFrames(data, 'id', [2, 3]),
  frameObjs = frames.map(frame => Object.fromEntries(frame));
  
console.log(frameObjs);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: Many thanks. It works, I needed to change the "key" in this part:  
`
const getFrame = (dataFrames, prop, value) => {
const [ , keyValues ] = dataFrames.find(([key]) => key === prop);
`